# Features from line segments

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

What is the best feature to differentiate line segment groups such as following? I would like to train line segments extracted from images for classification.
[image]

**Edit:** Sample from each class
[image]

Comment: I can suggest polar histograms.

Comment: To differentiate groups from each other or to differentiate groups among segments? What constitutes a difference?

Comment: @DonReba to differentiate groups(classes) from each other. Samples in each class have similar pattern.

Comment: Train MNIST-like CNN for this.